# Which polygons can be turned inside out by a smooth deformation?

Tags: gn.general-topology, convex-geometry, euclidean-geometry

Take a non-degenerate polygon with side lengths $\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$ in a convex configuration. What is the condition on the $a_i$'s so that the polygon can be turned inside out by a continuous motion that preserves the side lengths.

For example any triangle cannot be, but the unit square and unit hexagon can be, since you can collapse both to form a degenerate shape with zero area. A four sided figure can sometimes be inverted, sometimes not if the smallest side is too small.

Just working out the four sided figure could be interesting I think.

I suspect that it is possible iff you can find a configuration of zero area, where the area is defined as $\frac{1}{2}(x_1y_2-x_2y_1+x_2y_3-x_3y_2+\dots+x_ny_1-x_1y_n)$ where the $(x_i,y_i)$ are vertices of the polygon with i increasing from 1 to n as you progress around the polygon in order. It is trivial that if a deformation exists the area must change sign and hence be zero but the reverse implication may be more challenging. (Of course this doesn't solve the problem as this is not a condition on the side lengths but might be a useful observation).

**Update:** My conjecture that you can invert a polygon iff you can deform it into a configuration of zero area is incorrect due to the following counterexample based on the figure included in Joseph O'Rourke's answer:

[image]

The polygon on the left has 3 side lengths $\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}$ and $1+\frac{2}{\sqrt 3}$ and hence does not satisfy the criteria in the paper because $$2(1+\frac{2}{\sqrt 3})>(1+\frac{2}{\sqrt 3})+\frac{3}{\sqrt 3}.$$ However you can deform the left configuration into the one on the right which has zero area.

In addition you can slightly increase the short sides AB, CD, EF to create a negative area on the right configuration but still not satisfy the criteria for inversion. Therefore we cannot modify the conjecture to the obvious one that there must be mutually deformable configurations of both strictly positive and strictly negative area.

Therefore the two equivalence classes of configurations for a polygon that doesn't satisfy the criteria must sometimes contain a mixture of positive and negative area configurations.

Comment: @WalterNeff I mean a continuous motion that preserves the side lengths. In the case of a square squashing to line I meant that you take opposite vertices of the square and move them together keeping all sides equal so that the squares becomes a rhombus of smaller and smaller area until the area vanishes. I'll add this as a clarification to the question thanks.

Comment: Yes it should be, thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't update your question to include an answer.

Comment: @CJDennis It actually wasn't an answer to my question rather a refutation of a conjecture that I posed as part of my own observations related to the problem.

Comment: Just because you later realised that a conjecture was wrong doesn't make it a bad question, or need to be pointed out in the question. The answer does that perfectly well, and it doesn't reflect badly on you.

Comment: @CJDennis True but the point is that the conjecture wasn't part of my question, it was in my discussion of the question so I wanted to include an update to this, not answer my original question. I think this is ok as opposed to specifically answering your own question in your question which I agree is generally not!

Comment: @CJDennis It was also too big an example to fit in a comment :-)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This question was explored here:

> Lenhart, William J., and Sue H. Whitesides. "Reconfiguring closed polygonal chains in Euclidean $d$-space." *Discrete & Computational Geometry* 13, no. 1 (1995): 123-140; DOI: [10.1007/BF02574031](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02574031), [eudml](https://eudml.org/doc/131350).

From the **Abstract**: "It is shown that in three or more dimensions, reconfiguration is always possible, but that in dimension two this is not the case. Reconfiguration is shown to be always possible in two dimensions if and only if the sum of the lengths of the second and third longest links add to at most the sum of the lengths of the remaining links."

---

[image: BillSue1]

          
[image]

---

Comment: See also e.g. the work of Kapovich and Millson https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kapovich/EPR/plane.pdf or Farber and Schuetz https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0609140 for topological studies of moduli spaces of polygons.

Comment: Thank you Joseph, that's a very elegant result that should be better know given it is such a natural question to ask. I am still thinking about the question of whether having a configuration with 0 area is also equivalent to a shape being reconfigurable. I think this follows from the paper but I need to think a bit more about this.

Comment: @MarkGrant Thank you - interesting to see such sophisticated results arising from an elementary problem.

Comment: @IvanMeir: I added their Fig.1, which supports your zero-area criterion.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke Thanks, definitely looks plausible based on this.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke Actually I believe I found a counterexample to the zero area conjecture based on the figure in your answer - see my update.

Comment: @IvanMeir: Very nice example!